# Why would you name a Golang interface "Interface"?

Tags: go, interface, naming-conventions

There is only one convention I'm aware of in Golang for interface name - suffix single func interfaces with their method name plus "er". I've also noted another - `Interface`. As a package can only have one type with a name, I infer that it must be intended as the primary interface to the package - you could call this the "package interface".

My is there another reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming an interface type `Interface` isn't a convention–it's only used once in the standard library: [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

Maybe the name `Interface` isn't the best or most intuitive one–`Sortable` would be more intuitive–but I guess the Go authors chose that name because together with the package name it is still better: `sort.Interface` vs `sort.Sortable` (the latter repeats `sort`).

Comment: Maybe they should have named it `Able`, or even `Er`, for `Sort.Able` or `Sort.Er`. :-)

Comment: @torek Nice suggestions, let's hear what the Go authors say about them :)